# How can I put a negative time in a html5 input time tag?

Tags: html, time, attributes

I would like to be able to select in an html5 `<input>` **time tag** like this one

```
<input type="time" value="00:00:00" step="0.1">
```

also **negative** hours, like "-10:02:3.000".
How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it with the standard time input type.
It refers to the time of day, not absolute amounts of time.

You need a JavaScript solution for the functionality you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah. time is a point in time not a duration. Points cannot be negative :)

Answer (score 1):

You can not do that. Actually you can using css tricks but not recommended.

Either use text type and customized validation. Or define a user specific input type as required.